# vb.net- How to make any picture in a picture box round in shape

Tags: vb.net, rounding, picturebox

I am making an application in vb.net that has a good user interface, including the your account icon that includes a picture box. My question is that how can i make that image in the picture box round in shape?

Like This:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rUBq68ULDkTiFFv2uEiV_oQIh3wQIfhd

Comment: Maybe use a method to paint the bitmap so that anywhere outside the circle is set to white.

Comment: i don't want it to be white.....it should be transparent......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't normally provide code for a question that doesn't show an attempt but there are a few steps in the answer and it was easier to just write the code myself than explain them.  E.g.

```
'Get the original image.
Dim originalImage = PictureBox1.Image

'Create a new, blank image with the same dimensions.
Dim croppedImage As New Bitmap(originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height)

'Prepare to draw on the new image.
Using g = Graphics.FromImage(croppedImage)
    Dim path As New GraphicsPath

    'Create an ellipse that fills the image in both directions.
    path.AddEllipse(0, 0, croppedImage.Width, croppedImage.Height)

    Dim reg As New Region(path)

    'Draw only within the specified ellipse.
    g.Clip = reg
    g.DrawImage(originalImage, Point.Empty)
End Using

'Display the new image.
PictureBox2.Image = croppedImage
```

That will create an elliptical image with the same width and height as the original.  If the original is square then the final will be circular.  If you want a circle regardless of the aspect ratio of the original then you'll have to manipulate that in the appropriate manner.

Comment: sorry, " Dim path As New GraphicsPath " --this line has an error **Type 'GraphicsPath' is not defined.**

Comment: Use the Help menu to open the documentation and search for the `GraphicsPath` class to see what namespace it's a member of, then either qualify the name or import that namespace. You should never ask a question again without using that Help menu first. Only if you can't find what you need or don't understand what you find do you need to ask others. Always look for yourself first.

Comment: @Tejas2708 : Also check the suggested fixes. Visual Studio usually helps you by suggesting to import the type's namespace (if one is found).

Answer (score 0):

Though i see that you already found out the solution to your question, however here's a very simple workaround.

Assuming, your project is in `WinForms`, and you are using `Picture Box` control. The easiest way to achieve the round-image-look is to set the `Image` property of the `PictureBox` to an image that is round-shaped and is blank/transparent in the middle and white on the outside. Then , whatever image you set as a `BackgroundImage` , it will appear round-ish.

Here's a sample round-transparent image for you which you can set as `Image`(make sure to set `SizeMode` to stretch) and then set any picture as `BackgroundImage`.

[image: Image is white so it will blend with the background color of this page, just right click and save it]