# image appears outside of round border

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I have an image inside of a round picture box.  on the form it is fine.  when I save the image, the portion that is "outside" of the round picture box shows.
question: how to make the area outside of round picture box "not" show the image when saved?? Here is the Image on the form[image: Image on Form].

here is the saved image[image: Saved image]

VB.Net
PicCropImageRound is name of my picture box.

```
Save Function
    'Save current photo
            Dim strCurDir As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(LblOrigPath.Text)
            Dim strNewName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(LblOrigPath.Text)

            Dim x As Integer = PicCropImageRound.Width
            Dim y As Integer = PicCropImageRound.Height
            Dim bm As New Bitmap(x, y)

            PicCropImageRound.DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, x, y))

            PicCropImageRound.Image = bm
            PicCropImageRound.Invalidate()

            'Find image type
            Dim img1 As Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(LblOrigPath.Text)), True)

            Dim imageType As String = String.Empty

            If ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(img1.RawFormat) Then
                imageType = "JPEG Image"
            ElseIf ImageFormat.Bmp.Equals(img1.RawFormat) Then
                imageType = "BMP Image"
            ElseIf ImageFormat.Gif.Equals(img1.RawFormat) Then
                imageType = "GIF Image"
            ElseIf ImageFormat.Tiff.Equals(img1.RawFormat) Then
                imageType = "Tiff Image"
            ElseIf ImageFormat.Png.Equals(img1.RawFormat) Then
                imageType = "PNG Image"
            Else
                imageType = "Unknown Image Type"
            End If

            If imageType = "JPEG Image" Then

                'Save The image in PictureBox
                SaveImage(strCurDir & "\" & strNewName & ".jpg", PicCropImageRound.Image)
            End If
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciates.

EDIT:
after searching and found code sample that gets me close to desired effect.
[Crop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50872282/17415097)

```
Dim x As Integer = PicCropImageRound.ClientSize.Width
                Dim y As Integer = 
                PicCropImageRound.ClientSize.Height
                Dim bm As New Bitmap(x, y)

                PicCropImageRound.DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(0, 
                0, x, y))
                PicCropImageRound.Image = bm
                PicCropImageRound.Invalidate()                
                'New Code
                'Get the original image.
                 Dim originalImage = PicCropImageRound.Image
                  'Create a new, blank image with the same 
                   dimensions.
                Dim croppedImage As New Bitmap(originalImage.Width, 
                originalImage.Height)
 
                'Prepare to draw on the new image.
                 Using g = Graphics.FromImage(croppedImage)
                     Dim path As New GraphicsPath
 
                     'Create an ellipse that fills the image in both 
                     directions.
                     path.AddEllipse(0, 0, croppedImage.Width, 
                     croppedImage.Height)
 
                     Dim reg As New Region(path)
 
                     'Draw only within the specified ellipse.
                     g.Clip = reg
                     g.DrawImage(originalImage, Point.Empty)
                 End Using
 
                 'Display the new image.
                 PicCropImageRound.Image = croppedImage
```

as image shows, outside is not transparent??
will seek advise on that portion??

The new code results with this image.
[image: New saved image]

Comment: While I'm happy to admit far from my specialist topic, my eye immediately goes to `PicCropImageRound.DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, x, y))`.  Why if you're after a circle would you use New Rectangle?  Where x and y are the effectively the bottom left of your form (Circle width and height).  Can't help feeling you may actually want to do something background, set it too transparent maybe?